# como puedo unir dos datos de dos input en uno solo con un botón con java script

Tags: javascript, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito unir lo que dice en el cuadro de texto nombres con el cuadro de texto  apellidos con un botón en java script y que aparezca el ultimo cuadro de texto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>formularios</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quevivalaamistad.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="color">formularios</h1>

<form>
     
  <input type="text" name="" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del estudiante">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido del estudiante">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Unir" />
</form>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="" readonly >
```

Comment: Para qué tu pregunta no sea cerrada y bienvenida, añado al menos algún ejemplo ¿qué has intentado? Puedes darle a **Editar** y añades tu código. Aparte vas a obtener una mejor respuesta según tu código. De paso lee las políticas del sitio de como preguntar.

Comment: Aunque has editado tu pregunta, la misma sigue sin tener un [example] que nos permita ayudarte. Ampliando la descripción no es suficiente. Ya entendemos lo que quieres, pero para ayudarte necesitamos acceder a tu código para ver que elementos estás usando, como están dispuestos, que librerias de javascript estas usando, y un largo etc, que por mucho que amplies la descripción no te a servir para que te reabran la pregunta. Vuelve a [edit] la pregunta añadiendo el codigo o olvidate de tener una respuesta certera. Saludos!